# How do we get people to stop assuming that we have X-ray vision?

Tags: discussion, questions

One of the great banes of this site is the dreaded question that needs photos to answer, but lacks them, leaving everyone guessing at what it could be.  Anyone have any ideas how to get more folks to add photos of what's going on to their questions?

Answer (score 3):

See [this answer](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/940/2196) to what may be a duplicate question. It comes down to asking the user to post a photo in the comments, and if one is really needed to answer the question, then cast a vote to close with "unclear what you're asking" as the reason, or flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: I prefer using the "Not enough information" close reason, in the Off-Topic close reason list (Close > Off-Topic > Not enough information).

Comment: I agree these and the poster that never comes back are the two main reasons I vote to close things.